# Fibers of unbounded linear functional are dense

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'm supposed to prove that if $f$ is a discontinuous linear functional $H\rightarrow \mathbb C$, each of its fibers $f^{-1} \left\{ \alpha \right\} $ is dense. I already know the kernel, i.e $f^{-1} \left\{ 0 \right\} $ is dense, and I would like to say something like $f^{-1} \left\{ \alpha \right\} =v+ f^{-1} \left\{ 0 \right\}$ for some $v\in f^{-1} \left\{ \alpha \right\}$ by some sort of homogeneity to deduce all fibers are dense. However, I'm not sure how to prove this equality.

Lastly, in my exercise, $H$ was taken to be a Hilbert space, but think we just need $H$ to be normed (not even complete). Is this correct?

Comment: You can show that any non-zero linear functional is surjective. Then for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}, \exists v\in H$ such that $f(v) = \alpha$, so that $f^{-1}(\alpha) = v + \ker(f)$ as required. And yes, you don't need it to be a Hilbert space - any normed space will do.

Comment: @Prahlad: I suggest you write your answer as an answer, and not as a comment.